# Unable to save array to NSUserDefaults

Tags: nsuserdefaults

This is my first attempt at using NSUserDefaults. I've read every question & answer posted in stackoverflow regarding this subject, but still can't get it to work. I must be missing something basic. The array (allContacts) merely contains a few names and phone numbers. Unless I'm misunderstanding what's happening, both fields are NSStrings. Or are they just pointers to strings? If that's the case, how would I convert them to actual NSStrings? Here's my code to save the array:

```
- (BOOL)saveChanges
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:allContacts];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mutableArray forKey:@"allContacts"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    return 1;
}
```

Here my log:

```
2013-08-07 15:48:17.568 ImOK[5515:907] *** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
    "Brad Pitt, 1-917-297-1234",
    "Marilyn Monroe, 9179291234"
)' of class '__NSArrayM'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

This code "for(id contact in allContacts) { NSLog(@"%@", [contact class]); }" gives me:

```
2013-08-07 17:11:30.845 ImOK[5569:907] Contacts
2013-08-07 17:11:30.854 ImOK[5569:907] Contacts
```

so I guess they are not valid property values.
Incidentally, there was no intelligent reason for me to attempt to save the array as an NSMutableArray. I was just experimenting.

Comment: a) try logging the classes of the objects, with something like for(id contact in allContacts) { NSLog(@"%@", [contact class]); }

Comment: and b) why are you making a mutable array here? You're not mutating it. Just pass allContacts directly.

Comment: What is the type of the objects contained in allContacts?

Comment: were you able to solve your problem? did any of the comments or answers help?

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSUserDefaults

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.

If `allContacts` is an `NSArray`, just use that in your `setObject:forKey:` call. If it's an `NSMutableArray`, use:

`[allContacts copy]`

to get a non-mutable copy of the array.